# java MultiTouch application on windows?

Tags: java

Can we develop multitouch applications in java that runs on windows? what is the replacement events that we need to write in java for touch events like touch down, touch up and all that are used in .net framework.
im very new to this java programming so please help.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, Java does not come with support for multitouch. Have a look at the [MT4j](http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) framework.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking into something similar. I have been reading on [MT4j](http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) and it's seems promising. Obviously, it's very complicated compared to traditional event handling and tracking but they have same good documentation and examples on their site to get started.